# Robot Localization: How to set velocity using a service?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am using the robot localization pkg and my application requires to run multiple rosbags in a loop. The agent in all the bags does not necessarily start from 0 velocity. Is it possible to reset the velocity along with the pose every time there is a new bag encountered? Is it possible to have a rosservice to set the full state?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318070/robot-localization:-how-to-set-velocity-using-a-service?/) by [gandhigauri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31758/gandhigauri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any time you set the pose, the non-pose variables should also get reset. This is the code for the `setPoseCallback`:

1. [Create a measurement that is the size of the entire state](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/e1ea727ab8b9a2ba2a458948e3b77aae52f64b7d/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1992)
2. [Zero it out](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/e1ea727ab8b9a2ba2a458948e3b77aae52f64b7d/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1997)
3. [Update only the pose portion to non-zero values](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/e1ea727ab8b9a2ba2a458948e3b77aae52f64b7d/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2005)
4. [Reset the filter state](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/e1ea727ab8b9a2ba2a458948e3b77aae52f64b7d/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2008)

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gandhigauri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31758/gandhigauri/) on 2019-03-19**:
Thanks Tom! Is there any way to set the non-pose portions to non-zero values?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-03-20**:
Not right now, but it would be a straightforward change to add a `set_state` service that takes a nav_msgs/Odometry message instead, if you are so inclined.

**Comment by [gandhigauri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31758/gandhigauri/) on 2019-03-20**:
Thanks Tom! I added the new service and that gives me the desired output.